# Skip to absolute horizontal position in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabto

I tried to use the tabto package in math mode in order to skip to an absolute position, but it doesn't work. Is there a simple way to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{align}
Var(X + c)  = \tabto{6 cm} \text{rel. 184 pag. 62} \\
&= \mathbb{E} \tabto{6 cm} \text{proprietà 1 pag. 61}
\end{align}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `alignat` instead

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @egreg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(X + c) 
    & = &&  \text{rel. 184 pag. 62}    \\
    & = &&  \text{proprietà 1 pag. 61}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Zarko fantastic solution

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi, thank you!